# Model Relationships: efficiency in defining the relationship within the model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-5

A bit of a high-level question, more for the academics than the trench-diggers, I suppose.

## Question 1:

When defining a foreign relationship with another model, say, a one-to-many relationship, it is typically defined in the following manner:

```
public virtual ICollection<OtherModel> OtherModel { get; set; }
```

However, I have also seen it defined in the following manner:

```
private ICollection<OtherModel> _otherModel;
public virtual ICollection<OtherModel> OtherModel {
  get { return _otherModel ?? ( _otherModel = new List<OtherModel>() ); }
  set { _otherModel = value }
}
```

This does make sense to me: if no entries of this model are referenced from the OtherModel (a null value), then the null-coalescing operator ensures that a blank, empty collection of OtherModel is created. From what I can tell, it’s a safety measure.

However, an evolution of the above appears to be this:

```
public class ThisModel {
  // Assorted model items

  public virtual ICollection<OtherModel> OtherModel { get; set; }

  public ThisModel(){
    OtherModel = new List<OtherModel>();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not seeing how the two can be equivalent. The second code block above clearly uses the null-coalescing operator to call a blank list *ONLY* when `OtherModel` does not reference anything in `ThisModel`; when the resulting list would be null anyhow.

And when I read the third code block, I am interpreting it as a list of the `OtherModel` being created *every single time* `ThisModel` is called.

I was hoping someone could give me a bit of clarification on any differences between the two.

## Question 2:

On the flip side of the coin, we have required entries in the `OtherModel`. Normally we build the reverse relationship in the `OtherModel` like this:

```
public virtual ThisModel ThisModel { get; set; }
```

However I have also seen it defined in the following manner:

```
public class OtherModel {
  // Various model stuff

  private ThisModel _thisModel;
  public virtual ThisModel ThisModel {
    get { return _thisModel; }
    set {
      if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
      _thisModel= value;
      ThisModelId = value.ThisModelId;
    }
  }
}
```

The key thing is, because `OtherModel` has a required foreign key, if that foreign key ends up being force-fed a null entry, the `if` statement explicitly throws a null exception. I like this. It ensures that for required foreign keys, a null value cannot be used or cannot be introduced. It ensures that any such rejection is done long before anything reaches the DB in a CRUD operation, and acts as a backup in case the business logic (higher up in the stack, with the View Models) was accidentally not extended to cover that issue.

My question in this case is how to condense this into something more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. They are different, and the constructor version is actually an anti-pattern. In the constructor, you're initializing an empty list whether or not the list has a value or not. For example, if EF were to initialize an instance where the list does have a value, first the value would be set to an empty list, then it would be set again to the list it should contain by EF. Granted, it's not *that* inefficient to simply create an empty list, but you are still consuming some amount of RAM and CPU for the operation that end up being unnecessary.

The custom getter and setter version is lazy-set, so an empty list is only initialized when the value is null, meaning no wasted resources. Again, it's not a *huge* deal, but a ton of little inefficiencies like this can eventually add up to real problems (like death by a thousand cuts).

Just to add a further wrinkle, though: in C# 6.0 you can actually provide a default without using a custom getter and setter, though. So the following is really the most optimal way:

```
public virtual ICollection<OtherModel> OtherModel { get; set; } = new List<OtherModel>();
```

It works exactly the same as the custom getter/setter version, just without all the cruft.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I have been looking into the C# 6 features, but have not explicitly run across this example yet.

Comment: There's even more goodies in C# 7 and 7.1. Tuples, out variables, throw expressions, local functions: I'm not sure how I ever wrote code without them.

Comment: Ironically, that “anti-pattern” was something I also spotted in a video from Julie Lerman of EF6 fame: http://dddcommunity.org/ddd-contributors/julie-lerman-entity-framework-in-core-business-applications-and-domain-driven-design-approaches/ not sure if it exists as an anti-pattern there, but it’s what sparked this post.

Comment: I have much love for Julie. She's awesome. However, everyone should be fully aware that even experts do bone-headed things sometimes. None of us are immune to making mistakes. That said, I wouldn't even really fault her for this one. As I said, not using the constructor is a micro-optimization if anything. While it's technically wrong to do this in the constructor, in reality, you could probably do this all over the place in a large scale application and still not really incur any significant performance penalty.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I added a second question to my first one if you want to take a punt at that as well. *sits eagerly with sharpened pencil*

Comment: Sorry I didn’t add that second question along with the first, it slipped my mind. But at least they’re related.